# set 2D array as function and call it elsewhere as needed

Tags: c++

So i have this variable I would like to pass it as function to following code down which still not working yet but any idea about it?? I would also be pleased to know if we can add ctime to track the arrival of the user thanks for your help ..

```
bool spt_1 [15][12] = {0}
```

and this is the code which I want to pass it so I can call it later on somewhere in my code

```
int col = 1;
int row = 1;

for (col = 1 ; row < 16 ; row ++) {

  if (spot_1 [col][row] == 0) {

cout<<"There is a place reserved for you in spot, the first column , row number "<<" "<<row<<"."<<endl;

string choice;

do {

cout<<"\nDo you want to take that spot? Y/N.\n"<<endl;
cin>>choice;
cout<<"\n"<<endl;

transform(choice.begin(), choice.end(), choice.begin(), toupper); 
}while (choice != "Y" && choice !="YE" && choice != "YES" && cout<<"Wrong input!\n"<<endl);

cout<<"\nHave a nice day.\n"<<endl;
break;

 if (choice == "YES") {

spot_1 [col][row] = 1; // should change that specific 0 to 1 ( which means occupied )

 }

else  {

//it should reject count ++;

} 
 if (spot_1 [col][row] != 0) { // When there is no more place it should cout this and go search in a new array and do same as first one

cout<<"Sorry ,There is no more place available , But you can go to :\n"<<endl;   
    } 
   }
  }
}
```

thanks for your suggestions .

Comment: anyone can help . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a 2D vector instead of that array in the first place. But if you really need to do it with an array you could define a template function like this:

```
template <int Row, int Col>
void some_func(bool my_array[Row][Col])
{
    //do your stuff
    //here just printing the array and changing a value
    for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++)
            std::cout << my_array[i][j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    my_array[3][4] = false;
}
```

and call it in you program like this:

```
some_func<15,12>(spt_1);
```

**EDIT after comment:**

There is always a way, but it gets dirtier. 
I would consider this more a C then a C++ question and I'm not a native C speaker.
I would maybe do it this way, but there are probably better ways:

```
void some_func(void* my_pointer, int row, int col)
{
    bool* my_pointer_arr = static_cast<bool*>(my_pointer);
    for (int i = 0; i < row * col; i += col)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            std::cout << my_pointer_arr[i + j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    my_pointer_arr[3 * col + 4] = false;
}
```

Maybe just search for "C style 2D array to function" and you will get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help my friend but i'm not familiar with vector is it possible with standard void function ?